# What is wp_get_post_tags for media tags?

Tags: functions, tags

I'm trying to customize a function where I have

```php
wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
```

My need is to have this function querying media assets' tags, which I see the plugin called "attachment_keywords", instead of post tags.

If I understand correctly, `wp_get_post_tags` returns the "post_tags" taxonomy terms. How can I access "attachment_keywords" taxonomy terms?

Thanks

Comment: How you added tags to media  ?  Which plugin you have used  ?

Comment: I used WP/LR, from the post dump I see there is a "post_terms" array added to the post. I'd like to loop over the the post->post_terms to check for post->post_terms->name values

Comment: So did my answer help?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what you explained. What's the link between `wp_get_post_tags()` and `wp_get_post_terms()`? Why `terms` works for this specific case? What does it mean _so you would do the same for custom taxonomies_? I think you should explain what happens in the solutions you offer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand correctly, `wp_get_post_tags` returns the "post_tags"
> taxonomy terms.

Yes, except that the taxonomy is *`post_tag`* and not *`post_tags`*.

> How can I access "attachment_keywords" taxonomy terms?

[`wp_get_post_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_tags/) uses [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/), so you would do the same for custom taxonomies.

For example if the taxonomy (name/slug) is `attachment_keywords`, then:

```php
$tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'attachment_keywords' );
```

And that should work, but as suggested in the [documentation for `wp_get_object_terms()` that's used by `wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/#more-information), you might want to use `get_the_terms()` instead which caches the results and thus can help improve performance, specifically when *looping* over posts results.